# Do time based Workflow email alerts use latest details?

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I have various time based email alerts that fire when a record is created, although they might not be due to send until 30 days after the record is created. I can see them in the time based workflow queue. My question is if some details about the record change such as the owner or dates within the record will this then update the time based email even though it is already in the queue?

Many Thanks

Comment: There is no official documentation that i can find however I believe the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the Salesforce official [help page](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US).

> Time-dependent actions remain in the workflow queue only as long as
>   the workflow rule criteria are still valid. If a record no longer
>   matches the rule criteria, Salesforce removes the time-dependent
>   actions queued for that record.

Though it doesn't say anything about considering newer version of the record however since the workflow re-evaluates the criteria every time you update a record, its quite obvious that it will consider the updated record if only it still satisfies the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of this is yes, it will populate your email with the current data from the object at time of send. This would also be why your email stays in the queue only as long as your workflow rule criteria is still valid to keep it there.